# change bit according to message

Tags: python, tuples, pixel, bitwise-operators

I have a three-element `tuple` inside a list, and a message in 8-bit binary

```
list = [(15,103,255)]

message = '0110100001100101011011000110110001101111'
```

I need a function which will take simultaneous 3 bits of the message, then convert the each element from the `tuple` into binary, and replace it's first 3 bits by the bits from the message.

Eg : Step 1. `a =  message[0:3]`

```
         a = '011'
```

Step 2 :     `b = '{0:08b}'.format(15)`

```
         b = '00001111'
```

Step 3 :  `c = '01101111'`

Step 4 : `d = int(c,2)`

```
     d = 111
```

The new list should be

```
new_list = [(111,71,31)]
```

Comment: Is each tuple element an unsigned integer between 0 and 255 (inclusive)?

Comment: @@Hinam Mehra - what did You try already and what didn't work for You?

Comment: @@Tim Peters - Each element tuple is previously defined. But yes, it is in the range [0,255]

Comment: @@Vlad - I tried indexing and using the ' &' operator. But that just didn't include the '0' trailing forward.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, making guesses about some things that weren't clear.  I stuffed it in a class to make it easier to change:

```
class BitFiddler:
    def __init__(self, bitstring):
        self.bitstring = bitstring
        self.i = 0

    def fiddle(self, value):
        nextbits = self.bitstring[self.i : self.i + 3]
        self.i += 3
        nextbits = int(nextbits, 2)
        return (value & 0x1f) | (nextbits << 5)

thelist =  [(15,103,255)]
message =  '0110100001100101011011000110110001101111'
bf = BitFiddler(message)
print [tuple(bf.fiddle(value) for value in thelist[0])]
```

Output:

```
[(111, 71, 31)]
```

As a 1-liner:

```
print [tuple((v & 0x1f) | (int(message[i:i+3], 2) << 5)
             for v, i in zip(thelist[0], range(0, len(message), 3)))]
```

Comment: You can replace some of the logic skipping ahead 3 "bits" that you implement in your BitFiddler class with [Grouper](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). You'll also be able to pick a fill in, which may be necessary.

Comment: Uninterested in giving the OP an obscure itertools recipe here - I suspect this will be hard enough for them to grasp as-is ;-)

Comment: What happens in your example if `message = 01010` and there are still values to fill?

Comment: Don't care - for such a severely under-specified problem, I only care about giving the OP a usable **start**.  Many details have to be inferred from his example input.  One such inference is that his bitstring has **way** more bits than are needed - LOL ;-)

Comment: @@Tim peters - Do you know an easier way to do this ?

Comment: @HinamMehra, sorry, I don't know what you mean be "easier".  This is quite easy ;-)  Since some people mean "shorter" by "easier", I added a 1-statement version of the same thing.  However you do this, you **need** one operation to extract the next 3 bit characters, another to convert them to an integer, another to shift those into place, another to clear the high 3 bits, etc - there's no fluff here.

Comment: Another approach:  precompute a dict mapping (int, 3-character-string) tuples to the final result.  It would contain 256 * 8 = 2048 entries.  That would be much faster, and the code would just look up the answer.  But you've said so little about what you really need, it's impossible to guess whether that's appropriate here.